# FileStream "cannot access closed file"

Tags: c#, filestream

Why am I receiving the above error message when I use `using (fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))` but the programme executes perfectly when I replace it with `fileStream = File.Create(path);` ?

I want to append the console output to an external file. Here's my code:

```
 //copy console output to file in bin\Debug folder
    class ConsoleCopy : IDisposable
    {
        FileStream fileStream;
        StreamWriter fileWriter;
        TextWriter doubleWriter;
        TextWriter oldOut;
        class DoubleWriter : TextWriter
        {
            TextWriter one;
            TextWriter two;
            public DoubleWriter(TextWriter one, TextWriter two)
            {
                this.one = one;
                this.two = two;
            }
            public override Encoding Encoding
            {
                get { return one.Encoding; }
            }
            //Clears all buffers for the current writer
            public override void Flush()
            {
                one.Flush();

                two.Flush();
            }
            public override void Write(char value)
            {
                **one.Write(value);**//error thrown here
                two.Write(value);
            }
        }
        public ConsoleCopy(string path)
        {
            oldOut = Console.Out;
            try
            {
                **//fileStream = File.Create(path);** //runs alright with this line
                fileWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
                fileWriter.AutoFlush = true;
                doubleWriter = new DoubleWriter(fileWriter, oldOut);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot open file for writing");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return;
            }
            Console.SetOut(doubleWriter);
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.SetOut(oldOut);
            if (fileWriter != null)
            {
                fileWriter.Flush();
                fileWriter.Close();
                fileWriter = null;
            }
            if (fileStream != null)
            {
                fileStream.Close();
                fileStream = null;
            }
        }
    }//end of consoleCopy
```

I call this method in my main method as such:

```
 //pass output to ConsoleCopy method for copying to .txt file
        using (var cc = new ConsoleCopy("mylogfile.txt"))
        {
           DateTime theDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

            string custom = theDate.ToString("d");

            Console.WriteLine("User has logged in on " + custom);
        }
```

UPDATE:

The error was previously shown at `one.Write(value)`. I've managed to solve it though thanks to Peter. Thanks everyone for your contributions and help :)

Comment: Can you upload an example of how you use cc from your second code block?

Comment: Make sure to add exact exception and show line of code where it actually happen. I believe that code that fails actually not shown here at all.

Comment: Of note is that you should implement "Dispose()" such that it can be called multiple times without adverse effect. The streams and writers already do so, so you can call fileWriter.Dispose() and fileStream.Dispose() (instead of calling .Close() and .Flush()) in your class' Dispose() method and it would accomplish the same thing in a way that doesn't cause errors if those objects were previously Dispose()-ed.

Comment: Alright thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: If you're getting it before you write, then it's because I misread the question and putting the using statement in the ConsoleCopy constructor means that when the ConsoleCopy is finished being created, the FileStream is closed then. By the time you try to write to it, because it's already been closed you get that exception. The same solution would apply - leave the FileStream open and close it in Dispose() where it should be with the using statement in the main method.

If I understand correctly, you get that exception on disposal, right? If so, that's because what's happening is essentially that you're closing that stream twice.

```
using (var cc = new ConsoleCopy("mylogfile.txt"))
{
    // At this time, your filestream is created with the using statement.
    // Writing happens here.
    // Your filestream is closed at the end of the using statement inside of the ConsoleCopy constructor.
} 
// At this point, ConsoleCopy tries to call Dispose(), which flushes and closes everything again. However, this throws an exception because the using statement already closed the FileStream.
```

If your goal is to append to the end of the file and your Dispose() method closes everything internally, why not just replace

```
**//fileStream = File.Create(path);** //runs alright with this line
```

with

```
fileStream = File.Open(path, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
```

and let the using statement in your main close the streams internally for you?

Comment: How do you explain : why `FileStream fileStream = File.Create(path);` runs all right? Since both StreamWriter and FileStream implement IDisposable, it should throw error in both cases when putting them inside `using` block?

Comment: Because before, he was opening his file in a `using` block in the constructor. That meant by the time his object was constructed and he could try to call `write` on it, the `FileStream` was already closed. `File.Create(path)` worked because it left the stream open to write to. He closes it in the `Dispose()` method, which is the correct place to close it instead of the constructor now. The only difference is he wanted to append to his file, so instead of `File.Create(path)` he just had to call `File.Open(path, FileMode.Append)`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the write code outside of the `using` statement? You might be closing the stream before doing anything with it.

What happens when you run this:

```
using (fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{
  fileWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
  fileWriter.AutoFlush = true;
  doubleWriter = new DoubleWriter(fileWriter, oldOut);
}
```

Comment: OP should be geting exception on `Console.Write` calls after that using block because code replaces out with writer that soon will be closed...

Comment: I would get an error at "one.Write(value)"... Thanks for trying to help though. Cheers :)