# Cannot access a closed file .net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

wants to just add a text to an existing pdf using [itextsharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)
.and so far I have done.my code =>

```
    public FileStreamResult DownloadCertificate(string UserId)
    {
        //get user info using UserId from database
        //UserDetail UserDetail = db.UserDetails.Where(x => x.UserId == UserId).FirstOrDefault();
        string oldFile = Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/tsms/Certificate/Certificate-of-Completion-Award-Template-Blue.pdf");
        string newFile = Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/tsms/Certificate/newFile.pdf");
        // open the reader
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
        Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        Document document = new Document(size);
        // open the writer
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        document.Open();
        // the pdf content
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        // select the font properties
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
        // write the text in the pdf content
        cb.BeginText();
        string text = "Some random blablablabla...";
        // put the alignment and coordinates here
        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 520, 640, 0);
        cb.EndText();
        // write the text in the pdf content
        cb.BeginText();
        text = "Other random blabla...";
        // put the alignment and coordinates here
        cb.ShowTextAligned(2, text, 100, 200, 0);
        cb.EndText();
        // create the new page and add it to the pdf
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        // close the streams and voilá the file should be changed :)
        document.Close();
        fs.Close();
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
        return new FileStreamResult(fs, "application/pdf");
    }
```

the problem is when I am trying to access the method browser showing me error like below=>
[image]

I don't know why it's giving me this kind of error.

I tried to find the solution. and I find....
[FileStream "cannot access closed file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617289/filestream-cannot-access-closed-file)

but that is not enough for me.

and I also try to change some lines in my code. below =>

```
  // close the streams and voilá the file should be changed :)
  document.Close();
  //fs.Close();
  //writer.Close();
  //reader.Close();
  return new FileStreamResult(fs, "application/pdf");
```

but that change also doesn't help me. what I have done wrong in my code.(also how can I provide a download mode to the user.)

Comment: You have two questions. You've answered the first part of your question with your changed block "below=>" -- You are trying to access "fs" after you've closed it "fs.close". You want to save your FileStreamResult to a local variable, THEN close your document, filestream, etc...and finally return the local FileStreamResult variable. Your error message has given you the answer. Reread it and look at your variable names and where you're closing them and accessing them for clues. GL

Comment: @mjw Yah you are right. now a change `            //document.Close();
            //fs.Close();
            //writer.Close();
            //reader.Close();` but after that its showing me anothre error [link](https://postimg.org/image/vp3wesgb1/) can you say anything about that...

Comment: Change your FileStream constructor call to: FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's a problem with the FileStream. My educated guess would be the call to `document.Close();` is also closing the `FileStream`.

You could try NOT reusing the same stream but rather opening up a new read-only one (which will also reset its position, by the way) and use that for the result.